# less: Unexpected token AT_IDENT found netbeans

Tags: css, netbeans, less, netbeans-8

I am having trouble in integrating my html base project in netbeans. When i add all the files in netbeans web folder it gives this error "Unexpected token AT_IDENT found" as shown in screenshot. Anyone suggest some solution to resolve it

```
& when (@form-wizard = true){
    .wz-nav-off > li a {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        cursor: default !important;
    }

    .wz-icon-inline li > a .icon-wrap{
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: inherit
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: take a look @Harry

Comment: From a pure Less code point of view, I don't see anything wrong with that chunk of code alone. Maybe your problem is elsewhere. Is `@form-wizard` defined anywhere in your code? It should have a value set.

Comment: yes i know there is nothing wrong with code, this error came after i added this project to netbeans. is there any package that give support to less commands in netbeans?

Comment: I have the same problem with Laravel Blade templates `<label class="@yield('label-classes')">`. Have you found a solution?